# Project migration from Eclipse Luna to Neon

Tags: java, eclipse, import, migrate, eclipse-neon

I used to work in Eclipse Luna for Java programming, but then switched to netbeans. I want to swithc back to Eclipse, but now only Neon is available. When I try to import a project to the Neon Java EE IDE, (same as when I used Luna) either nothing loads, or everything that was in the folder loads with tons of errors, like "String cannot be resolved to a type". I have a decent amount of experience using netbeans, but have not used Eclipse in a very long time, and did not really know what I was doing when I used to use it.

The problems the IDE describes are as follows:

> Description: The project was not built since its build path is
>   incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the
>   build path then try building this project *project name*      Unknown Java
>   Problem

and ...

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The type java.lang.Object
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files ClientProxy.java    /filepath/Main  line 1  Java Problem
>   where no main class even exists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build path and check if  JRE library is in the build path.

Comment: That was the problem, kind of embarrassed I didn't realize it, thanks!